# Removing only the root domains from the array

Tags: python

I have an array in which URLs are stored like this:

```
['https://techcrunch.com', 'https://techcrunch.com/event-info/sessions-robotics/
', 'mashable.com', 'mashable.com/2018/01/09/fighting-robot-toy-ces-zeus/
', 'http://tech.co']
```

Now, what I would like to do is to remove those URLs if their blog version is available. For example techcrunch blog (https://techcrunch.com/event-info/sessions-robotics/) is already presented in the array so I want to remove (https://techcrunch.com). Similarly, for the mashable. But, not for the (http://tech.co) as there is no blog version availble from this domain name in the array.

The end result that I want should be from this:

```
['https://techcrunch.com', 'https://techcrunch.com/event-info/sessions-robotics/
', 'mashable.com', 'mashable.com/2018/01/09/fighting-robot-toy-ces-zeus/
', 'http://tech.co']
```

To this:

```
['https://techcrunch.com/event-info/sessions-robotics/','mashable.com/2018/01/09/fighting-robot-toy-ces-zeus/
', 'http://tech.co']
```

Comment: Is the root URL always guaranteed to appear in the array before the longer version(s)?
Will there only ever be 0, 1 or 2 occurrences of a domain name?
Will the protocol (or absence) be the same for all instances of the domain and its url?

Comment: Any attempts from your side?

Comment: @Spangen Actually no! The blog version will always comes before the actual root domain. I kinda messed up above. There will 2 occurrence of the website just like I mentioned above (for example: 'https://techcrunch.com/event-info/sessions-robotics/' AND 'https://techcrunch.com'). Yes, the protocol will always be the same for both root and the blog version.

Comment: @trollster No, I haven't tried anything I just stuck on this. Previously, I just wanted to remove duplicates from the array which I did but, I am not really sure how to tackle this particular problem.

Comment: So start with an algorithm that goes through your array to see if item `n` starts with the same characters as item `n+1` (which you might need to fix up to end in a `/`. If so, choose `n` instead of `n+1` . If not, you'll need some other logic....

Comment: @Spangen This method will take a lot of time thus affect the performance. Let's suppose I have 200 items in an array. In this case, I need to compare item 1 with all the remaining 199 items before proceeding to item 2 and campaign again with the remaining 199 items. This process will take (200 * 200 = 40000 iterations).

Comment: From your comments and example above it appeared that the root and full url versions are adjacent. That's what I was assuming. If not then you could do a O(n Log n) sort first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

```
x = list()
x = ['https://techcrunch.com', 'https://techcrunch.com/event-info/sessions-robotics/', 'mashable.com', 'mashable.com/2018/01/09/fighting-robot-toy-ces-zeus/', 'http://tech.co']
blog = list()
root = list()
duplicates = list()

for i in range(len(x)):
    z = x[i].split('.', 1)
    if('/' in z[1]):
        blog.append(x[i])
    else:
        root.append(x[i])


for i in range(len(blog)):
    for j in range(len(root)):
        if(root[j] in blog[i]):
            duplicates.append(root[j])

leftover = list(set(root).difference(set(duplicates)))

print(blog + leftover)
```

Result:

```
['https://techcrunch.com/event-info/sessions-robotics/', 'mashable.com/2018/01/09/fighting-robot-toy-ces-zeus/', 'http://tech.co']
```

Explanation:

Your list contains elements which are domains. So, I can see, anything that contains blog name, will have **"/"** followed by something. So, I first separated out all those links which already are **blog** links. The rest would automatically be a list of **root** domains.

In my second loop, I iterate through both the loops to find out which **root** domains already occur in the **blog** list. I put them under a list of duplicates and perform **SET DIFFERENCE** operation between **duplicates** and **root** lists. The result of this is then added to the initial **blog** list.

Not the most efficient method may be, but it should do the trick based on the sample data you have provided.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Just the way I wanted. Thanks a lot for helping me out. You're awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
urls = ['https://techcrunch.com', 'https://techcrunch.com/event-info/sessions-robotics/',
        'mashable.com', 'mashable.com/2018/01/09/fighting-robot-toy-ces-zeus/',
        'http://tech.co']

results = []
for url in sorted(urls, reverse=True):
    if not len(results) or results[-1][0: len(url)+1] != url + '/':
        results.append(url)

print(results)
```